# "ascii" codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, string, unicode, utf-8

I am using python 2.7 and used Chinese characters in my code, so...

```
# coding = utf-8
```

and the problem is part of my code, as follows:

```
def fileoutput():
    global percent_shown
    date = str(datetime.datetime.now()).decode('utf-8')
    with open("result.txt","a") as datafile:
        datafile.write(date+"   "+str(percent_shown.get()))
```

percent_shown is a string that includes Chinese characters

When I run it, I get:

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: ordinal not in range(128)

How to fix it? Thanks

Comment: Please post the stack trace. As stands you haven't told us which line has the error.

Comment: Can you show us what `print repr(percent_shown.get())` displays? The first problem is likely when you do `str(percent_shown.get())` but since we don't know what that is, its hard to guess.

Comment: Also, you write to a file... what encoding would you like to use for that file?

Comment: percent_shown is a tkinter StringVar, what I get() is percent_shown.set("中文"+str(int)), so part of it is Chinese, part of it is a str(integer).

Comment: I want the output file to be in utf-8 because I want to show Chinese characters

Comment: Hmm...., in python 2 `"中文"` is a strange thing. It may look like a 2 character unicode string if your terminal and editors are utf-8 enabled, but its really a 6 character utf-8 encoded string. Your goal is to get things to unicode so, somewhat counterintuitvely, you need to decode it. For instance, `"中文".decode('utf-8')` is `u"中文"`. The best solution of course is to move to python 3.x where unicode is native.

Comment: I asked you to post the result of `print repr(percent_shown.get())` so that we can know the type of this variable for sure. You are still making us guess what it is!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [PEP 263](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/), the coding declaration must match the regular expression `r"^[ \t\v]*#.*?coding[:=][ \t]*([-_.a-zA-Z0-9]+)"` so you need to get rid of the space between "coding" and the equal sign:

```
# coding=utf-8
```

This declaration tells python that the `.py` file itself is utf-8 encoded, but doesn't change the rest of the program. This is useful if you are writing unicode literals but you still need to cast them to unicde properly to make sure things work.

Since you haven't shown us what you are trying to print, I found some Chinese characters to demonstrate. I have no idea what they mean... so appollogies for anyone I insult!

```
foo = u"学而设"   # Good! you've got a unicode string
bar = "学而设"    # Bad! you've got a utf-8 encoded string that python
                 # thinks is ascii
```

I think you can fix your program with a few tweaks. First, don't try to decode datetime.now(). Its just ascii. It didn't change its return type just because you declared the source file encoding. Second, use the `codecs` module to open the file with the encoding you wnat (I'm assuming its utf-8). Now, since you are working with unicode strings you can write them directly to the file.

```
import codecs

def fileoutput():
    date = unicode(datetime.datetime.now())
    with codecs.open("result.txt","a", encoding="utf-8") as datafile:
        datafile.write(date+"   "+percent_shown.get())
```

Comment: Codecs is in Python 2.7?

Comment: So combine an ascii datetime string with Chinese characters defined in u"中文" in the datefile.write() would work?

Comment: @NicholasHuang - yes, `codecs` is in python 2.7 and lets you set an encoding when you open a file. In my example, I assumed that `percent_shown.get()` returns a `unicode` object, so I converted the date to unicode (`unicode(datetime.datetime.now())`) and now the write is just 2 unicode strings. It should work but you'll have to try it and let us know!

Comment: I'm not sure how tkinter handles unicode. You may have to do `percent_shown.get().decode('utf-8')` to get it to work.

Comment: Thanks, it worked with just percent_shown.get(). no need for decode. I wrote u"" on every chinese strings though.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have whitespace before the `=` in your coding comment. Try:

```
# coding=utf-8
```

See the regular expression in: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/

Comment: That's true, but the code shown is all ascii so it doesn't solve the problem. I think its the `str()` cast when writing the file.